# Does probability conditioning distribute over union?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lets say you have two events $A$ and $B$, and you know that $X$ is true. What can we say about $P((A \cup B) | X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\cdot \mid X)$ is a probability measure in its own right, so all the ordinary properties of probability measures apply to it. In particular, 
$$P((A \cup B) \mid X) = P(A \mid X)+P(B \mid X)-P((A \cap B)\mid X)$$
and if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (so $A\cap B = \emptyset$), then $P((A\cup B) \mid X) = P(A \mid X)+P(B\mid X)$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me that $P(...|X)$ is a probability measure in its own right.